# Deeplink didn't work properly

Tags: php, android, python, web, deep-linking

creating a deeplink form android studio, I uploaded assetlinks.json file into my .well-known folder on host.

every thing is OK on android studio deep link building tool but when I click on link in my website it does not open app.
my deep link configuration is like this:

```
<activity
       android:name=".activities.OrdersActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait">
       <tools:validation testUrl="https://myhost.com/cart/success" />

       <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

           <data
               android:scheme="https"
               android:host="myhost.com"
               android:pathPrefix="/cart/success" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

and the url i tried is this

```
https://myhost.com/cart/success?Authority=000000000000000000000000000000074139&Status=OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine. In which app did you click the link? They might be blocking deeplinks and open them in their app with [custom tabs library](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)?

You can try your deeplinks by executing adb shell command below:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://myhost.com/cart/success?Authority=000000000000000000000000000000074139&Status=OK"
```

You don't need to upload assetlinks.json file to your .wellknown folder inorder to implement deeplinks. It's required for applinks. Difference between an applink and a deeplink is, deeplinking needs user approval to launch your app while applinking does it automatically.

See the article below for more detailed explaination

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/

Comment: I open my link in Chrome for Android but it just reload and opens a page in my website